# Double Expansion on Array Index Windows Batch

Tags: arrays, batch-file, indexing, cmd

Inside the for loop I'm trying to access the element at index `count` in `CLs` (this line of code: `echo !!CLs[!count!]!!`) , but I'm not sure how to do this. I don't really understand how expansion works in this case, so what you see below it me trying something out of no where.

```
@ECHO off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

SET CLs[0]=#

SET /A count = 0
FOR /F "tokens=5" %%I IN ('some command') DO (
    echo !!CLs[!count!]!! :: THIS LINE
    IF NOT %%I == CLs[!count!] (
        SET /A count += 1
        SET CLs[!count!]=%%I 
    )
)

echo The item is %CLs[10]%
endlocal
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `Call Echo %%CLs[!count!]%%`?

Comment: This would appear to be an X-Y problem <https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem> Please post the *actual* problem you are attempting to solve. Are you attempting to find `%%I` in an established array of `CLs` (not the best name in batch since `cls` is a keyword) or add unique enties to the array `CLs` or what?

Comment: @Magoo I'm trying to make an array of just specific unique tokens from the command output. Does that help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the post [How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4095133) (see phase 5), the line `echo !!CLs[!count!]!!` cannot work, because the opening `!!` are collapsed to a single `!`, then `!CLs[!` is expanded to an empty string (assuming such variable is not defined), then `count` is returned literally, then `!]!` is expanded to an empty string and the final `!` is dismissed. Or in other words, delayed expansion cannot be nested.

You can use [`call`](https://ss64.com/nt/call.html) though to introduce another parsing phase, like this:

```cmd
call echo %%CLs[!count!]%%
```

---

The line `IF NOT %%I == CLs[!count!] ( ... )` is wrong, you must expand the right value too. However, `call if` will not help unfortunately, because `if` (like `for` and `rem`) is a special command that is recognised by the parser earlier than others, like `call`.

To work around that you can store the value of `!count!` in a [`for`](https://ss64.com/nt/FOR.html) meta-variable, like `%%J`, for instance, to introduce another parsing phase, and use `!CLs[%%J]!` then, like this:

```cmd
set /A "count=0"
for /F "tokens=5" %%I in ('some command') do (
    for %%J in (!count!) do (
        echo !CLs[%%J]!
        if not "%%I" == "!CLs[%%J]!" (
            set /A "count+=1"
            set "CLs[!count!]=%%I"
        )
    )
)
```

---

Another yet slower possibility is to put the relevant code into a sub-routine:

```cmd
set /A "count=0"
for /F "tokens=5" %%I in ('some command') do (
    call :SUB !count!
)

goto :EOF


:SUB
    echo !CLs[%~1]!
    if not "%%I" == "!CLs[%~1]!" (
        set /A "count+=1"
        set "CLs[%~1]=%%I"
    )
    goto :EOF
```

---

You may also take a look at the post [Arrays, linked lists and other data structures in cmd.exe (batch) script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10167990) about how to deal with such pseudo-arrays.

Answer (score 0):

```
ECHO ------------- START AT %time%

REM <!-- language: lang-dos -->
@ECHO Off
setlocal enableextensions ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q58209698.txt"

SET CLs[0]=#
SET /a clscnt[0]=0

SET /A count = 0
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%I IN ('type %filename1%') DO (
 SET "processed="
 FOR /f "tokens=1,2,3delims=[]=" %%a IN ('set cls[') DO IF /i "%%a"=="cls" (
  IF "%%I"=="%%c" (SET /a clscnt[%%b]+=1&SET "processed=y")
 )
 IF not DEFINED processed SET /a count+=1&SET "cls[!count!]=%%I"&SET /a clscnt[!count!]=1
)

FOR /L %%a IN (0,1,%count%) DO ECHO !clscnt[%%a]! times !cls[%%a]!

ENDLOCAL
ECHO -------------------------Second way -----------------
@ECHO Off
setlocal enableextensions ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q58209698.txt"

SET CLs[0]=#
SET /a clscnt[0]=0

SET /A count = 0
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%I IN ('type %filename1%') DO (
 SET "processed="
 FOR /L %%a IN (0,1,!count!) DO (
  IF "%%I"=="!cls[%%a]!" (SET /a clscnt[%%a]+=1&SET "processed=y")
 )
 IF not DEFINED processed SET /a count+=1&SET "cls[!count!]=%%I"&SET /a clscnt[!count!]=1
)

FOR /L %%a IN (0,1,%count%) DO ECHO !clscnt[%%a]! times !cls[%%a]!

ENDLOCAL

GOTO :EOF
```

I used a file named `q58209698.txt` containing some dummy data for my testing and chose to use the entire data line, having no suitable files where `token 5` existed.

Note that as a bonus, I've added `clscnt` - an array of occurence-counts.

Shown: two separate ways of achieving the aim of finding/counting the unique tokens. Naturally, if the `cls` array is pre-loaded with the required tokens, then it's basic-programmer's-play to adjust the code to detect/report occurrences of those tokens.

The two methods are similar. In the first, `set` is used to list the established variables starting `cls[`. The first `if` ensures processing only the array-name `cls`, then either it's a repeat (set `prcoessed` to a value and increment the occurrences-counter) or it's a new value (when the `for...%%a` loop ends, `processed` is still undefined) so record it.

The second way is more direct, using the value of `count` to specifically interrogate the values in the `cls` array.